# how can i add collection data to csv in blue prism?

Tags: blueprism, rpa

i tried to add collection data to Comma-separated values but not able to do if any one can help me on this it will be great help.

Answer (score 0):

I've done this, but I dont have access to BP right know and I cant get u any specs.

I've put that collection in to a txt file ale then a created separators.

I'll update this when I will get my BP accses again.